# GCM send message with conditions to large group of users

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing GCM to send message to android devices.
My server need to send different messages to different devices based on the user preferences settings. For now, I am considering of 2 approaches:

1) Save user settings to database server, run query to select the devices base on user settings and send message to these devices.

2) I will save user settings in local android device memory, server will always send message to all devices, when device receive the message, it will check with the local setting to decide whether to display the message to user.

Assuming that my app need to send message every minute and have about 500K users, which is the better approaches ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If your push notification is based on device settings, you can use the [Device Group Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications). You can use Device Group Messaging with your first approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send the same message to all users with a given preference settings, using topics might be better then either one.  The app can subscribe to the appropriate topics based on the user preferences, and you send your message to the topic address ("/topics/xxxxx") and GCM would make user the appropriate devices receive the message

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. May I know if there's any limit about number of topics per app and number of subscribed users per topic? Can I remove the outdated topics ?

Comment: I don't remember any explicit limitation on the number of topics, but you probably should check the documentation to be sure.  I remember a limit on the number of subscribers per topic, but as I remember the limit is over 500K.

Comment: update: As of today, GCM supports unlimited topics and subscriptions for each app. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Answer (score 0):

As Eugene said, you should consider topics. But even if topics don't work for you don't do your 2. Receiving a message wakes up the device, so that would waste battery for users who aren't intended to receive message. Approach 1 or topics are ways to go.